# G++ compilation, difference between mac os and ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, g++

I have a C++ project looks like the following,

```
-project/
    -include/   --> .hpp files
    -src/       --> .cpp files
    -bin/       --> for output executable
    -makefile
```

My makefile is the following,

```
g++ src/* -I include/ -o bin/program
```

When I run the `makefile`, it works perfectly on my Mac OS. However I tried to compile it using my Ubuntu and it did not work. I have the following error,

```
src/SomeFileName.cpp:1:28: fatal error: SomeFileName.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/main.cpp:1:28: fatal error: SomeFileName.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Should I change some part of the `makefile` for Ubuntu specifically? What is the problem?

My ubuntu g++ version:

```
x@x:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3
```

My main.cpp is the following,

```
#include "ListController.hpp"
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only one thing that I can suppose, that on your Mac the `PATH` environment variable also contains the `./`

So, you can try to change your makefile the following way:

```
g++ ./src/* -I ./include/ -o ./bin/program
```

Comment: I just tried it, does not work. The same error. I tried to do the same stuff on another windows machine, and it worked on windows too. But still does not work on ubuntu.